# JQuery - $.ajax POST does not send data with "<" symbol to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using the Jquery - $.ajax POST command for sending some data with "<" symbol to controller, but it's not fired the controller method,

```
    var xml="<user>";
     $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: '<%=Url.Action("MethodName","ControllerName") %>',
                data: { strXMLData: xml },
                success: function (data) {                            
                }
            });
```

i want to send the string value of **"< user>"** to my controller method, but its not fired the controller method, when i use the string like "** **user>****" means data will be send the controller method.... How to i send data with "<" symbol or any other solution for this ?

Comment: have you tried escaping it like \< ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply... i tried with escaping like "/<user>".. it's also not working, but i give "</user>" means it will working, the data is going with "/" symbol..

Comment: Maybe try using &lt; instead of < symbol, and &gt; instead > symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you you decorate your controller action with the [`[ValidateInput(false)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx):

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult MethodName(string strXMLData)
{
    ...
}
```

If you use ASP.NET MVC 3, that's all you need.

If you use ASP.NET MVC 1 or 2 but run in ASP.NET 4.0 you need to also set the following in your web.config for this attribute to have effect:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Comment: Hi Darin Dimitrov, Thanks for your reply...Its Great, i tried it will work fine, i am using framework4.0 and MVC2

Comment: This also worked with my MVC 4 app.  I had issues with users copy/pasting email text into the notes fields.  this fixed the problem with the <> symbols in the email header.